# Google +1 button on iOS

Tags: ios, html, google-plus

Has anyone had luck getting the Google +1 button to work on iOS or any other mobile devices?  I tried the new "HTML5 valid syntax" under [Advanced Options](http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Advanced Options of what? iOS settings? Development platform? Clock radio? Your coffee grinder?

Comment: @prophoto: You would do better to ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com/, but without describing your problem better and providing steps to reproduce, it risks getting ruled out there, too.

Answer (score 1):

The +1 button does not support mobile browsers just yet. It will not render on these browsers as a result.

**Update:** The +1 Button for the mobile web is now available. You should see it now :)